# What is the hardware/device that can switch a 5V and 12V (simultaneously) PC power supply lines?

Tags: power-supply, switches, switch-mode-power-supply, hard-drive

What I want to do is to switch the power supply lines (5V and 12V) for a hard drive. The 5V line is meant for data transmission, and the 12V is for the spinning disk DC motor.

I would like to control the hard drive power from PC through a means of serial port or USB, which I already have a device for. The difficulty is to switch on/off 5V and 12V simultaneously. I might need a specific hardware component to do this. Any suggestions on what might be helpful? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want an electrically or mechanically controlled switch?

Comment: One kink for you: the ATX power specification states that on power-up, the +12V rail voltage must always be higher than the +5V rail. Now I have no idea if a disk drive will care, but you may need to switch on the +12V, wait at least a few ms, and then switch on the +5V. Ideally, on switch off, this should be reversed.

Comment: Make sure you keep a backup of the data on your drive. Hot swappable drives deliberately *first* connect ground, then power supply rails and only data signals last. BTW: I nuked a disk myself in the past (IDE-age) in a similar way.

Comment: @HL-SDK I want a electrically controlled switch (mainly through GPIOs and USB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This 5 volt DPDT relay would work for your project](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/IM03DGR/PB1172CT-ND/1828462)

[What a relay is and how to understand the part I linked to you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay)

[image: Images of configurations.]

The abbreviations stand for

```
SPST – Single Pole Single Throw
SPDT – Single Pole Double Throw
DPST – Double Pole Single Throw
DPDT – Double Pole Double Throw
```

Comment: Does the 5V relay also switch the 12V power line?

Comment: @return0: The relay in HL-SDK's link is operated by 5 volts, and has two sets of contacts (two poles).  You use one pole to switch the 5 volts to the hard drive, and the other to switch the 12 volts.

Comment: @return0 the 5v refers to the activation voltage of the relay. The relay contacts can switch up to 220v.

Comment: I think my main question is that can the relay switch more than one power line (5V and 12V)? I know the activation voltage is a different concept.

Comment: Yes - a DPDT relay behaves like a DPDT switch. You control 2 different signals connected to one of two sources. In this case you want signal A to go between 5 and open with signal B going between 12 and open.